# Among COVID-19 patients who have died - what is the estimated distrubution of the time from symptom onset to death?

Tags: covid-19, clinical-study

In the
https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/who-china-joint-mission-on-covid-19-final-report.pdf I found:

> Among patients who have died, the time from symptom onset to outcome
>   ranges from 2-8 weeks

Is there a better study, or estimation? How the distribution of this variable looks like? Or at least, what is mean and standard deviation of this time?

I know it depends strongly on over-utilization of the medical resources of a particular country. So feel free to answer for any country/period you can get the information.

**Background:**

The reason why I would like to have this information is reverse estimation how many people were infected in the past (a few days ago). In countries that at least report the number of deads correctly, this could be really precise way how to guess number of infected. Especially for countries that are unable to test properly. Also, the statistics how many people die from respiratory issues could be avialable in countries that does not test diying persons at all.